# Meteor: Paypal Express Checkout integration

Tags: express, meteor, paypal, checkout

I'd like to implement Paypal Checkout Express in my webapp but have no solid findings. I've found a few meteor PayPal packages but it seems like they are paying using credit cards through PayPal, instead of using their PayPal account (I might be wrong here), so that's why I'm requesting for the checkout express. If anyone has any experience or knowledge, please do tell!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For one of my projects I used the `Paypal-rest-sdk` npm package, which allows me to handle PayPal payments, however credit card payments with this package only work in the US, UK & Canada. This page contains useful info on this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/paypal-rest-sdk, which also provides a link to a page with examples https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/tree/master/samples , which is especially useful in setting up your main PayPal code.

Comment: so users can login to paypal and pay with their paypal account, but not credit card payments?

Comment: Yes, when someone tries to complete a payment through credit card the payment simply hangs at some point without any clear error message. After some searching I figured it was because of the US, UK & Canada restriction, but it's a bit unfortunate it doesn't trigger a message or anything. I simply put an explicit message on my website that credit card payments aren't possible, which was fine in my case. But when users log in and pay otherwise everything works ok.

Comment: Appreciate the information Joos

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this package?

https://atmospherejs.com/reactioncommerce/reaction-paypal

Comment: do i need to use their reaction ecommerce package too?